# jsPDF removes spaces when using css font-weight bold

Tags: angular, jspdf, angular13

When I use font-weight bold jspdf makes the text lose spaces. See before and after pic below taken from the generated pdf.
[image]

The code of jsPDF is below.

html inside typescript:

```
<table style="width: 1100px; background: #5ba8da;padding:10px;">  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Project Name: ${row.project} </td> </tr>
</table>
```

Typescript:

```
 let doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a3');
 doc.setFont('courier');
 doc.html(this.template.body.summary(row), {
      x: 50, y: 65,
      callback: (doc) => {
        this.addFooter(doc);
        this.pdfSrc = doc.output("blob");
        this.busy = false;
      }
    });
```

Comment: @KJ what you mean by synchronize the css source?

Comment: The bigger problem for me is the bold having no space. Also font-size is not working...

Comment: I see, I am using the bold as an inline css in the above html code. However, when I added `font-family`, the spaces are now rendering correctly. However, I have a new problem, the font size couldn't change. I am using angular 13 with bootstrap, primeng. A cleaner version has no such issue. It seems like I have to remove libraries and see if the error is gone but it is difficult to get rid of any library as they are important. Also `doc.setFontSize` has not defined error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging all components and libraries, I found that `th, td` style was applied to a component that affected the style in pdf output. To solve the issue, I added the class of the other table so that it does not affect the pdf output css.